# Sending a message through an Android application

Tags: android

I got this code from some website. However, it isn't working for me. I get no errors, but the message isn't sent. I have added the appropriate permission along with required packages and a valid number.

```
public void sendSMS() {
        String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
        String message = "Hello World!";       
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
 }
```

Should I replace those **null** arguments with something else, to make it work?

This is where I got it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463338/Sending-a-SMS-Message-from-an-Android-Application

Comment: Did u add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> permission in AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: How do you know that its not working ??

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
```

Then in your activity

```
String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
String message = "Hello World!";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Add permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: nd like this 0123456789 hav any phone no. 

If you are trying with two emulator , then give the second emulator phone no instead of 0123456789

Comment: ohk ll try n ya can we send message from an emulator to mobile, i know thats senseless but stll for the clarification

Comment: dude , try it of with two emulators. then install your app nd try to send message to another mobile.
Just think it of, Emulator does not hav any network service provider , then how can we send from emulator to mobile.
Raise up Accept answer if this wat you want. happy coding :)

Comment: as @kathir said...its just emulator , its doesnt have neither network nor anything..Its just for testing the application :)

Comment: n ya can u just say me how to get back to previous activity once  i got next activity if a user click back button,bcoz now once i go to next activity it just exists the app i guess its bczo i use finish() method after i started the intent

Comment: @user3155869 yes thats the reason dude ,overwrite back button properties or delete finish()

Comment: @user3155869 just accept this answer or delete this question dude. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem, and I have also tested this in my device and also using two Emulator.

First of all you will need to give permission in AndroidManifest.xml file. These are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

After that you put your code here :

```
public void sendSMS()
{
    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
        String message = "Hello World!";

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);     

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Send"+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start SMS:

```
Intent intentsms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                                + ""));
                        intentsms
                                .putExtra(
                                        "sms_body",
                                        "SMS text ololo");
                        this.startActivity(intentsms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call below method

```
private void sendMessage(String phoneNumber) {

        try {
            if (phoneNumber != null) {

                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
                startActivity(smsIntent);
            } else {

                // Display mobile error
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Display error sending message

        }
    }
```

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```